# hive scan and select in one query

Tags: hive, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

I have a hive table, say `emp_details(name, dept)`.

In this table, I need to check if any records exists with `dept = ‘a’` then select those records. If no such record is found then only I will choose records with `dept = ‘b’`. The source data has either `'a'` or `'b'` as `dept` value and my result set will contain either `'a'` or `'b'` not both.

The problem is I am bound to use only one hive query for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate a_exist flag and use it for filtering:

```
    select name, dept 
       from 
           (select name, 
                   dept, 
                   (count(case when dept='a' then 1 end) over()>0) as a_exist 
             from test_a 
           )a 
      where (a_exist and dept='a')            --only a if exists 
         or ((NOT a_exist)and dept='b')       --return b if a not exists
;
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution is to partition the data on the basis of name and then take the first row. It will work good if I have multiple entries with same name but troubles me if the name has unique values. eg, solution is good for data set ('abc', 'a'), ('abc', 'b'); but creates problem when ('abc', 'a'), ('def', 'b'). Required result set in my problem is ('abc', 'a'). --select name, dept from (select name, dept, row_number() over (partition by e.name order by case e.dept when 'a' then 1 when 'b' then 2 end) rn from emp_details e) e where e.rn = 1;. Kindly correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: @Sandeep So, you do not need any rows dept='b' at all if any dept=a exist? Please provide source data and results example.

Comment: Source DataSet
(‘abc’, ‘a’),
(‘def’, ‘a’),
(‘ghi’, ‘b’),
(‘jkl’, ‘a’)
ResultSet
(‘abc’, ‘a’),
(‘def’, ‘a’),
(‘jkl’, ‘a’)
because ‘a’ was found in the data, if ‘a’ would not have not been found in any row then only give me output (‘ghi’, ‘b’)
Either ‘a’ or ‘b’ will be present in o/p. Let me know if it is clear.